# How can I refresh JWT token every "t" minutes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-effect

I am trying to implement an auto refresh for access-token every "t" minutes; I implemented a setInterval in useEffect (in the root component), which sends a request for a new access-token. When I run the code, at times the interval begins onMount and other times it does not run at all.

Another problem I am having that when I redirect the user to the login page,  I try to clear the interval and it continues running even after clearInterval.

If there is any other way to implement JWT refresh tokens at set intervals of time, I am open to them too.

```
 useEffect(() => {
      async function getRefreshToken() {
        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/refreshToken", {refreshToken}, {withCredentials: true})
        if (response.data.redirect) {
          clearInterval(refresh)
          history.replace(`${response.data.redirect}`)
          localStorage.clear()
        }} 

      const refresh = setInterval(getRefreshToken, 4000)
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-moore-wz8mf?file=/src/App.js). You can change the functions to match your case

#### Explanation

What you want is a ref to store the interval to clear it outside of useEffect. You can set the interval just like you do inside `useEffect`, and save the interval inside the ref:

```
const ref = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
   const interval = setInterval(...)
   ref.current = interval
}, [])
```

You need to use a [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-without-cleanup) inside `useEffect` to avoid memory leaks:

```
useEffect(() => {
   const interval = setInterval(...)
   ref.current = interval
   return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [])
```

Then, you can clear the interval whenever using :

```
clearInterval(ref.current)
```

Remember to use `useCallback` hook on your axios call function to make sure react doesn't unnecessarily renders.

Comment: Wow. Very clear and helpful explanation. Thanks for the useCallback tip too. I will test this and accept your answer.

Comment: What if the website is in background or not active, will setInterval() work?

Comment: @EzyHoo If that component is rendered, then yes, it will trigger setInterval. The token will expire at some point "t", if the user is not active, and then you can redirect/force the user to login again.